# Why is npm development server startup slow in emacs terminal mode?

Tags: npm, emacs, nuxt.js

I'm just getting back into trying some front end projects for the first time in a few years. Many npm-based javascript projects I try out end up taking a long time to start up in development mode even for Hello World-ish examples. In particular I'm trying out [Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/).

Dev server startup takes about 100 seconds, and nothing seems to get cached so restarts (*not* hot reloads) take the same amount of time. My research into the project and known npm issues did not turn up any definitive root cause or ways to improve this yet.

I'm using emacs 26.1 in terminal mode on a 2018 13" MacBook Pro with a core i5, 8 GB of ram, and an SSD.

When I run `npm run dev` to startup the `nuxt` dev server I get repeated `error in process filter: Args out of range: "\342", -1` errors related to some unusual characters they are using to try to make the output pretty. If I try the same thing in a vanilla Mac OS terminal the server startup goes 10x faster. Why do those errors occur, and why is it so much slower in an emacs terminal?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the repeated `error in process filter` issue may be caused by a [bug](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=150bdfe43acde8423612cbff4eafbbb88878b497) in term mode that was recently fixed but might still be an issue in my version of emacs.

As a workaround, the following can get the `nuxt` dev server running in ~10s instead of ~100s in an emacs terminal on my mac by filtering out the repeated lines about the modules being built:

```sh
$ npm run dev | grep -v modules
```

Note that I tried using npm's options to adjust the log level but none seem to filter this output. If anyone knows a more "official" way of filtering this, or even better, if you know how to make it such that it doesn't try to rebuild the modules on every dev server start up, I'd be interested to know.

Edit: it might make sense to adjust the `dev` script command in the package.json file to include the grep filter, that way you can still just type `npm run dev` and get the workaround.